# Examples of use thread safe singleton in multiple threads

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

There is thread safe singleton, but when we use singleton in multiple threads? When it may be helpful?

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort."

Answer (score 1):

I use stateless singletons as implementations of a strategy.  Being stateless, they are also thread safe and there is no problem testing them.

Where you get into problems is with stateful singletons. This leads to more interactions, especially in a multi-thread context, but just unit testing a stateful singleton in one thread is a pain (i.e. you have to reset the state between tests).  For this reason, many see singletons as an anti-pattern to be avoided.

A better approach to stateful singletons is to use dependency injection.  This way the code building the components only create one object, and that is passed to all the components which need it.